# action_rich_text rendering additional information

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, richtext

when rendering comment's body like `comment.body`  where body is `rich_text`

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :task
    has_rich_text :body
    validates :body, presence: true
    validates_presence_of :user, :task
    has_many_attached :files
end
```

it renders some additional info at the end why is it happening and how to remove it?

current rendering output is this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5fka.png)

why is there an additional images here

outer show

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@task, "comments") do %>
    <%= render "comments/index", comments: @task.comments %>
<% end %>
```

index

```
<div>
    <%= comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div>
            <%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(comment) do %>
                <%= render "comments/show", comment: comment %>
            <% end %>
        </div><br>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

finally show

```
<div>
    <div>
        <%= comment.body %>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: take the `=` out: `<% comments.each do |comment| %>`

Comment: @alex, "Vote to close questions that could be improved, may already have answers, or belong on another Stack Exchange site." I know there's a trend to close simple questions like this, but this site has bailed me out of "oh, duh" moments enough times that I always appreciate these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

The ERB tag with an equals sign (`<%= %>`) says "run this code and print the return".

The ERB tag without an equals sign (`<% %>`) says "run this code, but don't print the return"

So in this code:

```
<div>
    <%= comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div>
            <%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(comment) do %>
                <%= render "comments/show", comment: comment %>
            <% end %>
        </div><br>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

You're printing:

- the results of "comments/show" (what you want)
- the `turbo_frame_tag` (also what you want)
- the array result of `comments.each {}` (NOT what you want)

Just switch your tags:

```
<div>
    <% comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div>
            <%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(comment) do %>
                <%= render "comments/show", comment: comment %>
            <% end %>
        </div><br>
    <% end %>
</div>
```